# SQL Query with Entity Manager

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I've been thinking about how to create a proper query for my purpose but I'm not sure how should I approach it. It's a Spring web app, the website is similar to Twitter.

What I'm trying is to get the messages from who the user that requested the function follows. Saying shortly, a Twitter timeline, there are the classes:

**User class**

```java
//Imports

@Entity
@Table (name = "USUARIOS")
public class UsuarioVO implements Serializable {
//Not important class attributes and their getters/setters

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_FOLLOW",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FOLLOWED_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FOLLOWER_ID"))
    public Set<UsuarioVO> getFollowers() {
        return followers;
    }

    public void setFollowers(Set<UsuarioVO> followers) {
        this.followers = followers;
    }

    public void addFollower(UsuarioVO user) {
        followers.add(user);
        user.following.add(this);
    }
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "followers")
    public Set<UsuarioVO> getFollowing() {
        return following;
    }

    public void setFollowing(Set<UsuarioVO> following) {
        this.following = following;
    }

    public void addFollowing(UsuarioVO user) {
        user.addFollower(this);
    }



}
```

**Message class**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "MENSAJES")
public class MensajeVO implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2819136255644301650L;
    private Long id;
    private UsuarioVO sender;
    private String body;
    private Date fecha;
    private HashtagVO hashtag;

    public MensajeVO() {}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_SENDER")
    public UsuarioVO getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(UsuarioVO sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    @Column(name = "BODY")
    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "FECHA_ENVIO")
    public Date getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_HASHTAG")
    public HashtagVO getHashtag() {
        return hashtag;
    }

    public void setHashtag(HashtagVO hashtag) {
        this.hashtag = hashtag;
    }
}
```

The first approach I thought was getting the Set of following from the user and query each one of them to retrieve the messages, but there is a problem with that, I want to order the query by date, with that approach it would only order by date the message of each user, like:

- User1 messages ordered by Date
- User2 messages ordered by Date
- etc..

I was thinking about doing this with an Inner Join, but I'm not sure how should I build the query. An example of a working query:

```java
public Set<MensajeVO> findByUser(Long userid) {
        Query query = this.entityManager.createQuery(
                "SELECT m FROM MensajeVO m WHERE m.sender.id = ?1 ORDER BY m.fecha DESC", MensajeVO.class);
        query.setParameter(1, userid);
        return new HashSet<MensajeVO>(query.getResultList());
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

In SQL this is the query

> SELECT * FROM `mensajes` INNER JOIN `user_follow` ON mensajes.ID_SENDER = user_follow.FOLLOWED_ID WHERE user_follow.FOLLOWER_ID = ?

But I don't know how to get user_follow in Java, since is a ManyToMany field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, posting it in case it helps anyone:

```java
Query query = this.entityManager.createQuery(
                    "SELECT m FROM MensajeVO m WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UsuarioVO u JOIN u.followers fr WHERE fr.id = ?1) OR m.sender.id = ?2 ORDER BY m.fecha DESC", MensajeVO.class);
query.setParameter(1, userid);
query.setParameter(2, userid);
```

Search for the messages sent by people followed by the user or messages sent by the user.